# Trying to publish swagger.json file to atlassian wiki page

Tags: json, swagger, confluence

I am trying to publish swagger.json file to atlassian wiki page using swagger-confluence-cli-all-2.2-RELEASE.jar

Command used

```
java -jar swagger-confluence-cli-all-2.2-RELEASE.jar -u "<atlassian wiki url>" -b "<base64 encode username:password>" -a "35273" -k "TestPage" -g "true" -i "true" -s "swagger.json file" -t "Test1" -m "single"
```

But below exception I am getting

```
2017-04-13 10:52:47.215  INFO - [main] n.s.s.c.s.i.SwaggerToAsciiDocServiceImpl : Converting Swagger Schema to Ascii Doc...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: text must not be blank
at org.apache.commons.lang3.Validate.notBlank(Validate.java:451)
at io.github.swagger2markup.markup.builder.internal.asciidoc.AsciiDocBuilder.paragraph(AsciiDocBuilder.java:91)
at io.github.swagger2markup.internal.document.builder.OverviewDocumentBuilder.buildContactInfoSection(OverviewDocumentBuilder.java:127)
at io.github.swagger2markup.internal.document.builder.OverviewDocumentBuilder.build(OverviewDocumentBuilder.java:88)
at io.github.swagger2markup.Swagger2MarkupConverter.toString(Swagger2MarkupConverter.java:233)
at net.slkdev.swagger.confluence.service.impl.SwaggerToAsciiDocServiceImpl.convertSwaggerToAsciiDoc(SwaggerToAsciiDocServiceImpl.java:67)
at net.slkdev.swagger.confluence.service.impl.SwaggerToConfluenceServiceImpl.convertSwaggerToConfluence(SwaggerToConfluenceServiceImpl.java:73)
at net.slkdev.swagger.confluence.cli.SwaggerConfluence.runCLI(SwaggerConfluence.java:63)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try debugging mode, you'll see your `swagger.json` file has an empty object, called `contact`. So, you should fill in some of its properties, like name, `url` and/or `email`.

Comment: Thanks for answering but i solved  that day only , the problem was with confluence indexing page

Comment: The problem was the space key? How do you resolved the issue?